# How to change KendoUI DataSource Read from GET to POST request?

Tags: ajax, kendo-ui

I need help to change KendoUI DataSource of my dropdownlist from GET request to POST request.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Id)
.Name("PVDropDownList_Hotel")
.DataSource(datasource =>
                {
                    datasource.Read("GetMyHotels", "Hotel");
                })    
.DataTextField("Name")
.DataValueField("Id")
.Events(events =>
            {
                events.Change("PVDropDownList_Hotel_OnChange");
                events.Select("PVDropDownList_Hotel_OnSelect");
            })
.AutoBind(false)
```

)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This answer for asp.net mvc wrapper

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m.Id)
.Name("PVDropDownList_Hotel")
.DataSource(datasource =>
            {
                datasource => datasource.read(r => r.Action("GetMyHotels", "Hotel").Type(HttpVerbs.Post)) 
            })    
.DataTextField("Name")
.DataValueField("Id")
.Events(events =>
        {
            events.Change("PVDropDownList_Hotel_OnChange");
            events.Select("PVDropDownList_Hotel_OnSelect");
        })
.AutoBind(false)
```

)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as in [Kendo dropdownlist demo - remote datasource bind](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/remotedatasource.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#PVDropDownList_Hotel").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    url: "/Hotels/GetMyHotels",
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks. On top of your propose solution, is it possible to do the same using their ASP wrapper?

Comment: @JeeShenLee: something like this? `.Read(read => read.Action("GetMyHotels", "Hotels", new { name = "test", id = 2 }))`. I think these links can help you -[Pass additional parameters to Read ajax datasource method - MVC](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-web/grid/pass-additional-parameters-to-read-ajax-datasource-method---mvc.aspx) & [Problem with DataSource POST request for Read Operation](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-framework/data-source/problem-with-datasource-post-request-for-read-operation.aspx)

Comment: no. I know how to pass additional parameter. My question is how do i make the Read a "POST" method.

Comment: have a look at the second [link](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/kendo-ui-framework/data-source/problem-with-datasource-post-request-for-read-operation.aspx): `transport: {
            read: {
                type: "POST",
                url: URL,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json'
            },` I am not sure about ASP wrapper for datasource read for `POST`.